# MySQL dump specific values in DB

Tags: database, rows, mysql

I want to make a dump file of a DB, but all I want from the DB is the rows that are associated with a specific value. For example, I want to create a dump file for all the tables with rows related an `organization_id` of `23e4r`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The tools that ship with MySQL don't offer this functionality, although it shouldn't be very difficult to build upon them to create your own that does.  You might, for example, consider using [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html).

Comment: that's not entirely true. mysqldump has a --where option, so `mysqldump -u<user> -p<password> --where="organization_id=23e4r" <database> <table> > dumpfile.sql`

Comment: @pala_: I never knew that!  Kudos++ to you.  That said, one would still have to build a custom tool to apply that table-by-table, no?

Comment: well, assuming a bash shell it's pretty trivial to loop over a series of table names

Comment: @pala_: Maybe.  Might have to extract the list of tables from the db; and the filter criteria may differ in each table... but in any case (and as I said in my first comment), a script (bash or otherwise) shouldn't be very difficult to build.

Comment: agreed. especially as the truly annoying part would have been formatting the insert statements if you had to take care of that part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysqldump has a `--where` option, which lets you specify a `WHERE` clause, exactly as if you were writing a query, eg:

`mysqldump -u<user> -p<password> --where="organization_id=23e4r" <database> <table> > dumpfile.sql`

If you want to dump the results from multiple tables that match that criteria, its:

`for T in table1 table2 table3; do mysqldump -u<user> -p<password> --where="organization_id=23e4r" <database> $T >> dumpfile.sql;done`

Assuming you are using a bash shell, or equivalent

Comment: NB: "*[a `-pyour_pass` or `--password=your_pass` option on the command line... is convenient but insecure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/password-security-user.html)*".

Comment: the password is masked in 'ps' output, and you're unlikely to have shell access on a shared host where there are likely to be people snooping anyway. if you're in a position where someone CAN sniff your password from executing that, they probably already have all your data anyway